# Beamer doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: beamer

I was trying to make a presentation using beamer, when suddenly I got the following error message:

[image]

I don't know why it does this, because I've never had to use `sansmathaccent` before.

I tried running old files that used to be fine, however they get the same error message now as well. Even the most simple of files:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{Hello $A$}
\end{document}
```

gets the error message. What is/could be going on?

N.B. I recently (two days ago) ran an update for all my packages. Could this have something to do with it?

---

Edit: By now I've installed both `sansmathaccent` and `filehook` because the error message said so. Now it shows this error:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 450 n
>   ot found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

as soon as you include any maths to the document. **Note** If i type `Hello $\mu$` everything is fine. Ordinairy letters are causing trouble.

Comment: If I run your file with texlive2014 I see in the log `(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
Package: sansmathaccent 2013/03/28`   If you use texlive or miktex try using the package manager to install or update sansmathaccent?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Installed `sansmathaccent`. Now it wants me to install `filehook`. I find this all very strange, since I never had any problems with beamer so far. And as I said: even files that used to run fine, now don't anymore...

Comment: I don't really use beamer much but it's not that strange that it affects old files presumably beamer has been updated at some point and depends on some more packages so any use of beamer now requires them

Comment: Could you add an example document and either edit in or (if necessary) e-mail the log (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk). Loading `sansmathaccent` should work fine: it certainly seems to for most users.

Comment: @JosephWright I have send you an e-mail. I hope I followed your instructions correctly.

Comment: Email discussion has solved this: it's a map issue so I've marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @JosephWright Would it be better if I delted the question?